# Auto position textblock

Tags: c#

i'm currently trying to position my textblock in a way where it would automatically load below the next textblock after eg i click a button. (Its like a messenger , just that the text are set by me depending on events)

Other than scrollviewer to contain more textblock if it overshoot the screen, what do i need to make that work? or do i have to set a textblock there and hide it :(

I'm currently testing it out in sketch flow, would be nice if someone can tell me what to use to get this done or refer me somewhere relalted

Thank you!
Regards,
RAinbow

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StackPanel` control to put the `TextBlock` controls in. It will stack the text blocks below one another.